# How to add text in header with HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html, web-testing

[image: images]

I am trying to move the list items inside of the header above without affecting the size of the header, can anyone tell me how?

The code from my index.html is below

```
<header>
  <div id="service-buttons">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Unblacklisting</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">iCloud Removal</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Clean IMEI</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Buy & Sell</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Reported Lost</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Sim Cards</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

this is the code in my styles.css

```
header #service-buttons {
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: add HTML for Home, About to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  ...
}

header #service-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px; // change according to your need
  right: 4px; // change according to your need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set padding instead of margin:

```
header #service-buttons {
  padding-top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here this code will be helpful for you:
Apply on id service-buttons

```
#service-button  {   padding:8px;   margin-top:20px;  }
```